# How can I make the npc look at the agent with the head or using the transform.lookat?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When both the agent the droid on the right and the npc on the left meet they are also rotating facing each other and the agent seems to be looking at at the npc but the npc is frozen this position since I'm disabling the npc animator component.

Now I want to make the npc also look at the agent.

The npc in this case I can change his head and also the top end of the head position and rotation.
It looks like when I disable the animator that the npc is facing down. I can make the npc changing animation to idle but still not sure how to make him look at the agent droid.

[Npc facing down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfTUw.jpg)

I can change the head rotation on the X so it will looks more like he is looking at the agent :

[Changing the head rotation on X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We7DN.jpg)

If I'm using transform lookat the npc is falling on his back :

[Using lookat the npc is falling on his back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIucb.jpg)

In the end I see that also the agent droid is not looking at the agent.but the agent droid don't have the head part I need to rotate the whole droid on the X

What I want to do is when both npc and agent rotating each other that they will also look at smooth each other.

The droid have the components : Animator , box ocllider , rigidbody , navmeshagent

The npc have the component : Animator

This is the script I'm using for the rotation(meeting) in the method VisitNpcs :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    public List<GameObject> npcs;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    private int destPoint = 0;
    private int damping = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        var wayPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        foreach (GameObject waypoint in wayPoints)
        {
            points.Add(waypoint.transform);
        }

        npcs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Npc").ToList();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        GotoNextPoint();
    }


    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    }

    void VisitNpcs()
    {
        var npc = npcs[Random.Range(0, npcs.Count)];
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(npc.transform.position, agent.transform.position);

        if (distance > 7)
        {
            agent.destination = npc.transform.position;
            var collider = agent.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
            if (collider != null)
            {
                collider.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (distance < 2.5f)
        {
            agent.isStopped = true;

            npc.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;

            Vector3 lookPos = agent.transform.position - npc.transform.position;
            lookPos.y = 0;
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            npc.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npc.transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
            //npc.transform.LookAt(agent.transform);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.


        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            GotoNextPoint();
        }

        VisitNpcs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to look smooth, you could use a Coroutine and to set the time allowed to this rotation: Here we allow 2s to rotate to PositionToLook.. The time specified adjusts automatically the speed of rotation

```
    StartCoroutine(RotateToDirection(player, target.position, 2f));
```

---

```
public IEnumerator RotateToDirection(Transform transform, Vector3 positionToLook, float timeToRotate)
{
    var startRotation = transform.rotation;
    var direction = positionToLook - transform.position;
    var finalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    var t = 0f;
    while (t <= 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToRotate;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, finalRotation, t);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.rotation = finalRotation;
}
```

so you launch 2 same coroutines one for NPC and the other for Droid.

I dunno how is done your NPC, but i suggest you to create an empty GameObject and put all elements of the head like children and you rotate the Empty Gameobject.. i suppose the rest of body has an animation...(legs, feet..)